# Can a DLL launch a word file?

Tags: c#, dll

I have a DLL which after computation identifies a specific word file that needs to be opened. Can I have DLL open the specific word file, or return the path to the specific program calling the DLL and let the program handle the opening of the DLL file.

It would be great if there could be a possible solution where a DLL can launch a file.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It being a DLL makes no difference. As long as the code executes and has permission to the file then you can open it.

You will need to use something like `Process.Start()` but use the ShellExecute option with it so that it loads the associated program (most likely Word).

Answer (score 3):

You can use a DLL if you want, it really doesn't matter. As long as you have something to call the code in the DLL, then it will work just like it would in an exe.

```
public static void OpenWord()
{
    Process.Start(@"C:\Worddoc.doc");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I'm missing something since on the face of it this seems quite straightforward. Doesn't matter if its a dll or not. There's a [link, using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharplanguage/thread/5db48b80-59ec-44e7-afdd-04c53f4526fc) on the msdn site which shows you how to do what you're after.

The last time I did something like this was with ShellExecute but this seems to be the "new" way.